# Team foundation and 64-bit windows, can't install?

Tags: tfs, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

So is it a certified answer that you can't install Team foundation on windows 2008 64-bit?

**Update**

Is it better just do install it on windows 2003 or 2008?

Answer (score 1):

short answer is [no](http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2008/09/15/can-i-run-tfs-on-a-64-bit-os.aspx)

Rereading I need to make clear for double negative, read link, official is that you can't but there is a workaround if desired.